# Vue router - navigate to parent route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Is there a way to navigate from a child route to its parent route (or parent of parent) using Vuejs router needing to manipulating route/state names? [Angular](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_go) has/had a shortcut `^` route name which allowed navigation to the parent. I couldn't find anything similar for the Vue router.

The use case is that the child data is deleted (and thus the component showing it) and so the parent should become the current route.

Comment: Maybe have a look here https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/216#issuecomment-721261945